# i cant call a function on the address bar without including the index file

Tags: php, laravel-5

i am new to laravel and using laravel 5.so i added a

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('contact', 'WelcomeController@contact'); //this is wat i added

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

to the routes.php file then created a public function contact to echo 'contact me' upon being called in the WelcomeController.php file .

```
public function contact()
{
    return 'Contact me!';
}
```

}

the problem comes when i call the 'contact' function on the address bar all i get is 404 not found.help

Comment: Exactly how are you "calling" it on the address bar?

Comment: when i run it.but i figured out the problem and solved it.thanks for ur contribution.